# How to create conda env with both name and path specified

Tags: anaconda

OS: Windows 10

It's fine to create an env with either name or path, but it doesn't work with both name and path:

Command:

```
conda create -name myname --prefix D:\proj\myconda\myname
```

Error:

```
conda create: error: argument -p/--prefix: not allowed with argument -n/--name
```

So how to create an env both with a specific name and path?

The benefit from that is:

1. It's more convenient to remember a shorter nick name for the env.
2. It's better to move the path to other drives to save space of the default C system drive in Windows OS.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Because it would be more convenient to assign the new env a short nick name rather than a long path, and there is not much space in my C drive.

Comment: Also why can't the env file `-f` be specified with prefix `-p`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Create conda environment with prefix:

```sh
conda create --prefix=path/to/envname # C:\path\to\envname for Windows users
```

Make sure that the directory specified is added to `envs_dirs` configuration

```sh
conda config --append envs_dirs path/to/envname # again, change if using Windows
```

*Tip: If you are keeping multiple environments under a directory (e.g. /path/to holds multiple conda environments), then you can*

```sh
conda config --append envs_dirs path/to # again, change if using Windows
```

and conda will pick up on all environments stored in `/path/to`.

After this step, conda should recognize that you want to include envname in your named environments. You can verify with:

```sh
conda info --envs
```

which should return something like:

```
# conda environments:
#

envname     /path/to/envname
```

Finally, to activate the environment, all you should need to do is

```sh
conda activate envname # replace envname with your environment name from prefix
```

Comment: ...and now my PowerShell prompt is `(C:\Users\MyUser\src\project_dir\.conda\envname) PS C:\Users\MyUser\src\project_dir\`

Comment: after adding a path:
conda activate "F:\gd\dev~MDS\02 [DATA GEN]\faker.python\myCondaPythonEnv"

conda info --envs will list the long path environment without a short env, meaning in order to activate path env we need to supply all path:
conda activate "F:\gd\dev~MDS\02 [DATA GEN]\faker.python\myCondaPythonEnv"

$ conda info --envs
# conda environments:
#
base                     C:\tools\Anaconda3
my1stenv                 C:\tools\Anaconda3\envs\my1stenv
                         F:\gd\dev~MDS\02 [DATA GEN]\faker.python\myCondaPythonEnv

Comment: Thank you for how to do the append of the env_dirs. I wish I learned this config years ago.

Answer (score 16):

create a folder wherever you want to keep you environment files, inside the folder run:

```
conda create --prefix=yourenvname
```

When you wish to use this env, move to the folder in which you ran the previous command and do:

```
source activate yourenvname
```

Or

You can run:

```
conda create --prefix=path/yourenvname
```

This will create environment named "yourenvname" in the specified path.

Comment: This solution doesn't work for my Windows OS: (base) D:\proj\myconda>conda create --prefix=envname
Solving environment: done
...
(base) D:\proj\myconda>conda activate envname
Could not find conda environment: envname
You can list all discoverable environments with `conda info --envs`.

Comment: `conda config --append /path/to/directory/containing/env`. Running this will make conda look for the environment files in specificed folder.

Comment: Thanks! It works with: conda config --append envs_dirs D:\proj\myconda\envname

Comment: Hello. Sorry but what is the value of envs_dirs here: i'm on ubuntu and my anaconda is at ~/anaconda3. Thanks!

Comment: @mctrjalloh Maybe you can try to set envs_dirs with the installation path of the env, such as: conda config --append envs_dirs /anaconda3/envs/$specific_env_name.

Comment: @mctrjalloh and for anyone else looking into this topic the official docs are [here](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/use-condarc.html#specify-environment-directories-envs-dirs) regarding the `envs_dirs` parameter.  I manually edited the `.condarc` file to get things working.

Answer (score -1):

First create your custom environment as usual and then rename it as follows.

From [Conda's documentation](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#activating-an-environment),

After activating an environment using its prefix, your prompt will look similar to the following:

```
(/absolute/path/to/envs) $
```

This can result in long prefixes:

```
(/Users/USER_NAME/research/data-science/PROJECT_NAME/envs) $
```

To remove this long prefix in your shell prompt, modify the env_prompt setting in your .condarc file:

```
$ conda config --set env_prompt '({name})'
```

This will edit your .condarc file if you already have one or create a .condarc file if you do not.

Now your command prompt will display the active environment’s generic name, which is the name of the environment's root folder:

```
$ cd project-directory
$ conda activate ./env
(env) project-directory $
```